# Why does my code run fine in node but gives "unexpected token" when trying to use browserify?

Tags: javascript, web, browserify

When I do `node index.js` my file runs without errors but as soon as I do,
 `browserify index.js --standalone foo > app.js` I get this error:
 `Unexpected token (369:8) while parsing /path_to_file/index.js` - for reference here is the function containing line 369:

```
function createType(attrs = {}) {
    return {
        name: '<missing name>',
        aliasOfName: '',
        arrayOf: null,
        optionalOf: null,
        baseName: '',
        base: null,
        fields: [],
        serialize: serializeUnknown,
        deserialize: deserializeUnknown,
        ...attrs

    }; <------ Line 369

}
```

When I comment out the function, the same error comes again but for a completely different line. I cannot figure out why this is happening since the file runs fine when I run it with node.

**Edit:** I just tried using `browserify -t es6-default-params index.js --standalone app.js` to support the es6 syntax but now I am getting this error: `Line 501: Unexpected token =>` Here is line 501:

```
function getTypesFromAbi(initialTypes, abi) {
    let types = { ...initialTypes };
    for (let { new_type_name, type } of abi.types)
        types[new_type_name] =
            createType({ name: new_type_name, aliasOfName: type, });
    for (let { name, base, fields } of abi.structs) {
        types[name] = createType({
            name,
            baseName: base,

        Line 501 -------> fields: fields.map(({ name, type }) => ({ name, typeName: type, type: null })), 

            serialize: serializeStruct,
            deserialize: deserializeStruct,
        });
    }
    for (let name in types) {
        let type = types[name];
        if (type.baseName)
            type.base = getType(types, type.baseName);
        for (let field of type.fields)
            field.type = getType(types, field.typeName);
    }
    return types;
} // getTypesFromAbi
```

Comment: Are you using any built in node.js modules such as `fs`, `os`, or anything else that cannot be [polyfilled/shimmed](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#compatibility)?

Comment: `createType(attrs = {})` do you have browserfy configure to handle es6 default parameters?..  https://github.com/esnext/es6-default-params

Comment: @Keith hmm I just tried that but now I get a different error for an arrow function: `Error: Line 501: Unexpected token =>`

Comment: I've not used `browserfy`, but I'm surprised as default it won't parse`es6` stuff.   You could now try -> `https://github.com/esnext/es6-arrow-function`  Another idea is to use `webpack`, with webpack if your targeting modern browsers it will pass arrow functions & es6 default params etc.  Looking at github, both of those have not been updated for a while now, so is `browserfy` even supported nowadays?

Comment: @Keith idk. I've always used browserify. sigh. I think the solution is to use babel. I will try with this later.